# How to open an app via a link sent through SMS

Tags: android, sms, react-native, deep-linking

I have a React native Android app, and I want to open it from a link sent through an SMS (deep linking).

I have researched online and I have added the following to the AndroidManifest file - (Application/Activity).

```
 <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="xxxxnativeapp" android:host="createpassword" /> 
 </intent-filter>
```

Is there any way to test this by sending an sms from one mobile to another with a link. If so how can i create the link `xxxxnativeapp://createpassword` which I can send as SMS
just to test. which should open the app.

Just to test I tried creating a Native android application to have a `href` in a text view which opens a URL but not the app. I think opening an app from another app is totally different from 
opening an app from a link. correct me if I am wrong.

I also tried sending `xxxxnativeapp://createpassword` sending this via gmail but I did not succeed as gmail strips out the link if I send it this way.

Apologies I am so new this so wanted to know if any one has tried opening an app from a link which is been sent as an SMS.

please suggest any ideas how I can test this.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to make the link look like a URL, which is easy to do. Simply change the scheme to `http`

```
<data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="xxxxnativeapp"
      android:pathPrefix="/createpassword" />
```

And now you can use http://xxxxnativeapp/createpassword as a clickable link

Worth nothing that this is not possible on iOS